# Show whole text in query result in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql (mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2). and i am create a column named  **external_password** 
with  description   **external_password | varchar(200) | null =YES  |     | default =NULL** and inserted data.

When I try preform a select operation through  command line i got the following result,

```
mysql> select external_password from login_user WHERE user_name = 'abc@123';
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| external_password                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| $S$DEjrvXeeDgACuXAN0XkyM6FEPTFcHLcNqV..3SBHxQBpwR9wN7Fd |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But this not showing the full character.  between these substring {LcNqV..3SBHxQB} there are lot of other characters are hidden. how can i get the full text by command line??
please help me

NB: i am using using the ubuntu. Also in a situation i can't use phpmyadmin or any other mysql user interfaces.

Comment: You are using mysql version 14.14 ?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Comment: what is the substring being hidden ? post it..

Comment: @Alexander As i mentioned in my NB i am unable to use any kind of gui interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ego`. this **might** display more text compared to the table view.

```
mysql> select external_password from login_user WHERE user_name = 'abc@123'\G
```

here are other options you can use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: here's another link about the \G option. http://pento.net/2009/02/27/the-g-modifier-in-the-mysql-command-line-client/